# Netsuite Mass update Class field

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

A client was using a custom Fund field to classify every transaction. I am trying to migrate that field to the netsuite class field. I have created a process that pulls each transaction reads the fund field and updates the class field through their rest service. the problem is that they have a lot of Journal entries and it is takin a long time. Is there a way to do this faster, perhaps a database query.

Answer (score 0):

You can

- generate CSV files including the transaction type, internalid and custom class field
- run a script to transform the files so that:

  - each file contains only one transaction type
  - each file contains the internal id and new class name/id
  - each file is limited to the current size restrictions for csv imports
- map and import the resultant CSV files.

Depending on the number of CSVs to import you may find it useful to script that as well.

One way to do that would be:

- upload the files to the Netsuite file cabinet
- create a script to submit the uploaded CSVs using the N/task module. You'll need a saved csv mapping per transaction type.
- your script could be a map reduce script or a scheduled script. You might create a custom record that references each file. The CSV Job Id and status would be saved there and you'd poll the task id for status (with a scheduled script) and record success or failure.

Of course you can also create scripts in Netsuite itself that will turn search results (or other data) into CSV file objects and submit them for processing. There are potentially issues paging and governance so unless this was an ongoing need not something I'd likely explore but thought I'd mention it.